# why does Blend suck at compiling?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, expression-blend

about 10% of the time when I go to compile code that should compile, blend fails. I know the code should compile because w/o changing a thing it will compile in VS just fine. The really weird thing is that about 50% or more of the time, after compiling in VS and I come back to blend, it compiles. >_<

So, why does blend suck at compiling? and is there a way to make it as reliable as VS?

~N

Comment: Closed this because other than saying it sucks there's not much to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I think I figured out how Blend makes its compilation decisions.  Some of the oddities might be explained by my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191270/why-isnt-expression-blend-4s-designer-working-whenever-we-use-build-configurati).

Answer (score 0):

Like Sam said, my guess is that it doesn't have to do with the compiler but rather with the state of the project that's loaded. If you add a new class file in Visual Studio and then reference that class in an existing class, Blend will notice you've chanegd the existing class and prompt you to reload the file.  But until you build in Visual Studio, it won't notice you've changed the project and added a new file.